# How do I get to store a downloaded file with Java and Jersey?

Tags: java, download, jersey

I use Jersey for building RESTful services and currently I'm stuck on something that, I thought, shouldn't be too hard.

I manage to GET the file I want to download, but I do not know how to save it.

I searched for answers on the web, but I didn't find anything useful enough to fill in the gaps in my knowledge.

Can you, please, give me a hit how to go on in order to save the file in a location on hdd? Any code samples are going to be highly appreciated!

```
              Client client = Client.create();

            WebResource imageRetrievalResource = client
                    .resource("http://server/");
            WebResource wr=imageRetrievalResource.path("instances/attachment");
              MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
              queryParams.add("item", "1");

              Builder wb=wr.accept("application/json,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");

              client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("user","pass"));

              ClientResponse response= wr.queryParams(queryParams).get(ClientResponse.class);

              String s= response.getEntity(String.class);
              System.out.println(response.getStatus());
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using the `File` class?

Comment: @Viruzo: yes, no matter how stupid it sound I didn't manage to save the File instance=

Comment: Can you post your relevant code?

Comment: @Virusso: I think this is what is relevant - the rest is just setting the url and accept types for the WebResource. The important part is that I get resporse status "200", which means that I got my file (or file stream) I only cannot save it.

Comment: @Virusso: I added the rest of the code.

Comment: I meant the part relevant to trying to save the file, i.e. where you used the File class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the answer to my question:

```
      File s= response.getEntity(File.class);
      File ff = new File("C:\\somewhere\\some.txt");
      s.renameTo(ff);
      FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(s);
      fr.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Rest easy Client this is what I did.

```
    String fileServiceUrl = "http://localhost:8081/RESTfulDemoApplication/files";
    RestEasyFileServiceRestfulClient fileServiceClient = ProxyFactory.create(RestEasyFileServiceRestfulClient.class,fileServiceUrl);

    BaseClientResponse response = (BaseClientResponse)fileServiceClient.getFile("SpringAnnontationsCheatSheet.pdf");
    File s = (File)response.getEntity(File.class);
    File ff = new File("C:\\RestFileUploadTest\\SpringAnnontationsCheatSheet_Downloaded.pdf");
    s.renameTo(ff);
    FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(s);
    fr.flush();
    System.out.println("FileDownload Response = "+ response.getStatus());
```